# how can i remove /sub1/ and direct all wordpress in this subfolder to root?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

My wordpress blogs installed in root of site :

```
site.com/blog1/
site.com/blog2/
site.com/blog3/
site.com/blog4/
site.com/blog5/
```

I want put them in sub folder like this :

```
site.com/blogs/blog1/
site.com/blogs/blog2/
site.com/blogs/blog3/
site.com/blogs/blog4/
site.com/blogs/blog5/
```

Is there quick way like .htaccess functions or ... , that blogs link address stay like before ?(site.com/blog1 instead site.com/blogs/blog1)

Also all of post , page links also redirect to root ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must redirect requests from /sub1/ like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub1/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ sub1/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

What's inside your .htaccess now?

Comment: thank you .in website root there is no .htaccess file ,

Comment: I put this .htaccess codes in root folder but does not work. but thank you very much.

Comment: If your website don't have .htaccess file, probably you have nginx. Find configuration file (you must login to ssh of your server and find .conf file of your site). Add this code inside "server" block: